# What is an Entity Relationship Diagram called with example data?

Tags: database-design

Sometimes there is alot that a basic entity relationship diagram doesn't reflect.  I have seen, and often make diagrams that include a few rows of data for each table, because this tells you alot more about the relationships and the design.

Is there a name for these types of diagrams?  I am tempted to call it a "use case" of the data model.

Comment: nice question, I always use these and find them very helpful. But I have never known what they are called either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen a diagram that is an ERD with a few sample rows for each table, but I have seen diagrams that are intended to show examples of entities with particular attribute values and their relationships with other entities.  These are called **instance diagrams**.

This would be very similar to what you are asking about, except that I wouldn't say that they show "a few" rows, but rather one row of the "main" entity and possibly more than one of related child entities.